# Install Grub from Windows

Tags: grub2, windows, mbr

I've recently updated my Windows 10 to a newer version. It sadly overwrote the MBR. Now I have to reinstall Grub but I don't have any USB stick nor can I burn DVDs. Can anyone help me, get linux back up and running? What I need is a method to write grub to the mbr within windows.

Thank you very much!

Uwe

Comment: I haven't tried this one, but it looks promising:  https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/ that is given your system is using UEFI

Comment: This might not be necessary. Try to boot into BIOS and check boot options there. Or maybe there's a key for boot device selection on startup.

Comment: Well thank you very much guys. I found a method how to bring grub back. I press the assist button on my laptop select boot from drive then it says no operating sYstem found. If I then reboot I see grub. But as soon as I booted up windows on the next boot no grub is shown anymore. Then I have to repeat that to bring grub back. I tried disabling hyperboot or how it's called but it doesn't help.